# Python 3.x slowness

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have code that runs 24 hours a day and there are 2 threads in it. They threads only start once and yet I have a `if __name__ ==" __main__ "`. But after 3 days the code starts to become extremely slow and does not execute the functions correctly. Can anyone help me solve why this is happening? If it is some kind of "cache" that I have to clean or if python does not respond very well with code running 24 hours a day?

example of the code

```
def A():
    ...
    While True:
    ...code...
def B():
    ...
    While True:
    ....code....


...

Starting functions ('a' and 'b') by threading

...

While True:
   ... Code ...
```

edit:

I am using an amazon server, so I believe that the TCP protocol is not influencing. I don't necessarily know if it's the thread that is slowing it down, but something is making it extremely slow to the point that it stops working ...

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that your threads are getting slower? Have you made a timer to monitor the time eacho thread begin and finishes? Running 24h/7 with decrease in productivity is caused by invasion on your machine due to  unsolicited UDP packets and TCP connections . Monitor your system with hack tracer sotware for 3 days. Python should not lower productivity over time.

Comment: I am using an amazon server, so I believe that the TCP protocol is not influencing. I don't necessarily know if it's the thread that is slowing it down, but something is making it extremely slow to the point that it stops working ...